# Reading Arabic from JSON file

Tags: python, json

I want to read JSON file in Python that contains Arabic text but the Arabic text is appear like that:

```
ط§ظ„ط³ظژط¹ظژط§ط¯ظژط©ظگ ظ„ظژظٹظگط³ظژطھظŒ ط§ظ„ط­ظژطµظŒظˆظژظ„ظژ ط¹ظژظ„ظ‰ظژ 
ظ…ط§ظژ ظ„ط§ظ†ظژظ…ظ„ظگظƒظژ ط¨ظژظ„ ظ‡ظگظٹظژ ط£ظ†ظژ ظ†ظژظپظ‡ظŒظ…ظژ 
ظˆظژظ†ظگط¯ط±ظژظƒظژ ظ‚ظژظٹظگظ…ط©ظڈ ظ…ظژط§ظ†ظژظ…ظ„ظƒ
```

How can I read the correct Arabic letters?

```
import sys
non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)
print(x.translate(non_bmp_map))
```

`x` is parameter that contains Arabic value from JSON file.
I expected to get this sentence :السَعَادَةِ لَيِسَتٌ الحَصٌوَلَ عَلىَ ماَ لانَملِكَ بَل هِيَ أنَ نَفهٌمَ وَنِدرَكَ قَيِمةُ مَانَملك but I get ط§ظ„ط³ظژط¹ظژط§ط¯ظژط©ظگ ظ„ظژظٹظگط³ظژطھظŒ ط§ظ„ط­ظژطµظŒظˆظژظ„ظژ ط¹ظژظ„ظ‰ظژ ظ…ط§ظژ ظ„ط§ظ†ظژظ…ظ„ظگظƒظژ ط¨ظژظ„ ظ‡ظگظٹظژ ط£ظ†ظژ ظ†ظژظپظ‡ظŒظ…ظژ ظˆظژظ†ظگط¯ط±ظژظƒظژ ظ‚ظژظٹظگظ…ط©ظڈ ظ…ظژط§ظ†ظژظ…ظ„ظƒ

Comment: you could show (in question) oryginal data, expected result (and full error message if you get one)

Comment: I expected to get this sentence  :السَعَادَةِ لَيِسَتٌ الحَصٌوَلَ عَلىَ ماَ لانَملِكَ بَل هِيَ أنَ نَفهٌمَ وَنِدرَكَ قَيِمةُ مَانَملك but I get ط§ظ„ط³ظژط¹ظژط§ط¯ظژط©ظگ ظ„ظژظٹظگط³ظژطھظŒ ط§ظ„ط­ظژطµظŒظˆظژظ„ظژ ط¹ظژظ„ظ‰ظژ 
ظ…ط§ظژ ظ„ط§ظ†ظژظ…ظ„ظگظƒظژ ط¨ظژظ„ ظ‡ظگظٹظژ ط£ظ†ظژ ظ†ظژظپظ‡ظŒظ…ظژ 
ظˆظژظ†ظگط¯ط±ظژظƒظژ ظ‚ظژظٹظگظ…ط©ظڈ ظ…ظژط§ظ†ظژظ…ظ„ظƒ

Comment: btw: as I said in previous commend - you should show it in question, not in commend. It was important information in question - not all read comments.

Comment: @furas it's comment, and original

Comment: What is `x`? Where did it come from? You said you are trying to read a file, please post that part of your code as well.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't mentioned if you're using Python 3 or 2. In Python 3, the strings are unicode, by default.

If you use Python 2, use `codec`:

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open('unicode.rst', encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
    print repr(line)
```

Ref: [Unicode How-to](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data)

---

It is possible, however, that your input data isn't correctly encoded. In that case, you can try using [`ftfy` package](https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/python-ftfy).

`ftfy` implements several heuristics to fix broken/inconsistent unicode encodings. From the docs:

```
>>> from ftfy import fix_encoding
>>> print(fix_encoding("(à¸‡'âŒ£')à¸‡"))
(ง'⌣')ง
```

Comment: Hahahahah. There's a python called "ftfy"? xD What exciting times we live in!

Comment: it is not work . notepad show that the encode is  ANSI

Comment: @فاطمهالطاهر Do you mean `Windows-1252` by `ANSI` encoding? In that case, you should change to appropriate `encoding=` bit.